# Itext7 Reading a PDF in c# (with Hebrew)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

Need some help
I have a pdf, and I just need to read it and store it content in DB.
From some reason, I couldn't find a simple example of doing that using Itext 7

another thing, the content is in Hebrew, at first I used iTextSharp, but the content I got is in reverse order, so I have two options:
1. fix the reverse code
2. maybe find a more normal code maybe in Itext7 which don't have this problem.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

    for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++) 
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

        currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));

        var res = ConvertToHebrew(currentText);
        text.Append(res);
    }
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

The convertToHebrew function is not perfect for me, so I hope to find something which work without me trying to fix things.

Comment: You use the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`. This strategy returns the characters in the order they are drawn by the instructions in your pdf. Unfortunately the only other strategy included in itext explicitly sorts left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Thus, either you implement a different strategy or you keep using `convertToHebrew` or something similar.

Comment: That being said, can you explain what you do those encoding gymnastics for?

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF document that contains right to left scripts like Hebrew or Arabic is properly formed, then the content stream of the page will contain `/ReversedChars` instructions that wrap right-to-left text snippets. iText 7 is able to deal with such instructions and extract right to left text correctly from properly formed documents.

This functionality is implemented as a part of `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. To use it you basically have to replace `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` with `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` in your code. You should also call `SetRightToLeftRunDirection(true)` for the new `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` instance but you should notice the difference in the result even without this flag.

That being said, if the document was formed improperly (or not completely properly depending on how you consider it) and does not contain `ReversedChars` instructions then iText 7 cannot help you at the moment. At some point extraction of right to left scripts even for not completely proper PDFs will likely be possible with iText 7 but this is something for the future.